# Can't catch keys press events in GLFW

Tags: c++, glfw

The piece of code you find below draws a cube with a camera inside of it.
I don't understand why when I press `escape` key or the right, left, up and down arrow keys the program doesn't catch the event.

Inside `key_callback` I've added `std::cout << key << std::endl;` expecting to see on the console the identifier of the pressed keys, but everytime I press any keys nothing is printed in the console.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>

using timer = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <GL/glew.h>
#else
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#endif
#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795f
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "lodepng.hpp"
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtx/norm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtx/rotate_vector.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#pragma comment(lib,"user32")
#pragma comment(lib,"gdi32")
#pragma comment(lib,"opengl32")
#pragma comment(lib,"glew32")
#pragma comment(lib,"glfw3")
#endif

glm::vec3 camera_position(0.0f, 0.0f, 6.0f);
glm::vec3 camera_direction(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glm::vec3 camera_up(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

using timer = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
timer::time_point start_time, last_time;
float t = 0.0;
float dt = 0.0;
bool    translate_forward = false;
bool    translate_backward = false;
bool    translate_right = false;
bool    translate_left = false;
bool    rotate_up = false;
bool    rotate_down = false;
bool    rotate_right = false;
bool    rotate_left = false;
bool    rotate_z_left = false;
bool    rotate_z_right = false;
bool    sky_on = true;
bool    sun_visible = true;
bool    earth_visible = true;
bool    moon_visible = true;

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

GLuint tex_flag;

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    std::cerr << description << std::endl;
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    std::cout << key << std::endl; 
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_UP)
    {
        if (action)
            rotate_up = true;
        else
            rotate_up = false;
    }
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_DOWN)
    {
        if (action)
            rotate_down = true;
        else
            rotate_down = false;
    }
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_RIGHT)
    {
        if (action)
            rotate_right = true;
        else
            rotate_right = false;
    }
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_LEFT)
    {
        if (action)
            rotate_left = true;
        else
            rotate_left = false;
    }
}

// Shader sources
const GLchar* vertexSource =
#if defined(__APPLE_CC__)
"#version 150 core\n"
#else
"#version 130\n"
#endif
"in vec3 position;"
"in vec3 color;"
"in vec2 coord;"
"out vec3 Color;"
"out vec2 Coord;"
"uniform mat4 model;"
"uniform mat4 view;"
"uniform mat4 projection;"
"void main() {"
"   Color = color;"
"   Coord = coord;"
"   gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);"
"}";
const GLchar* fragmentSource =
#if defined(__APPLE_CC__)
"#version 150 core\n"
#else
"#version 130\n"
#endif
"in vec3 Color;"
"in vec2 Coord;"
"out vec4 outColor;"
"uniform sampler2D textureSampler;"
"void main() {"
"   outColor = vec4(Color, 1.0)*texture(textureSampler, Coord);"
"}";
const GLfloat vertices[] = {
    //  Position                Color               Texcoords
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,    0.15f, 0.33f, 0.55f,    .25f, 0.0f, // 0
    0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,     0.15f, 0.33f, 0.55f,    0.5f, 0.0f, // 1

    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,    0.15f, 0.33f, 0.55f,    0.0f, 1.f / 3.f, // 2
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,    0.15f, 0.33f, 0.55f,    .25f, 1.f / 3.f, // 3

    0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.5f, 1.f / 3.f, // 4
    0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   .75f, 1.f / 3.f, // 5

    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 1.f / 3.f, // 6
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 2.f / 3.f, // 7

    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   .25f, 2.f / 3.f, // 8
    0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.5f, 2.f / 3.f, // 9

    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   .75f, 2.f / 3.f, // 10
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 2.f / 3.f, // 11

    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   .25f, 1.0f, // 12
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.5f, 1.0f, // 13
};


const GLuint elements[] = {
    0, 3, 4,  0, 4, 1,
    2, 7, 8,  2, 8, 3,
    3, 8, 9,  3, 9, 4,
    4, 9,10,  4,10, 5,
    5,10,11,  5,11, 6,
    8,12,13,  8,13, 9
};

GLuint vao;
GLuint vbo;
GLuint ibo;
GLuint shaderProgram;
GLuint textures[1];

float t = 0;

void check(int line)
{
    GLenum error = glGetError();
    while (error != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        switch (error)
        {
        case GL_INVALID_ENUM: std::cout << "GL_INVALID_ENUM : " << line << std::endl; break;
        case GL_INVALID_VALUE: std::cout << "GL_INVALID_VALUE : " << line << std::endl; break;
        case GL_INVALID_OPERATION: std::cout << "GL_INVALID_OPERATION : " << line << std::endl; break;
        case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY: std::cout << "GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY : " << line << std::endl; break;
        default: std::cout << "Unrecognized error : " << line << std::endl; break;
        }
        error = glGetError();
    }
}

void initialize_shader()
{
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
}
void destroy_shader()
{
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
}

void initialize_vao()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // shaderProgram must be already initialized
    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

    GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

    GLint cooAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "coord");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(cooAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(cooAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
}

void destroy_vao()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ibo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
}

void initialize_texture()
{
    glGenTextures(1, &textures[0]);

    std::vector<unsigned char> image;
    unsigned width, height;

    unsigned error = lodepng::decode(image, width, height, "cube3.png");
    if (error) std::cout << "decode error " << error << ": " << lodepng_error_text(error) << std::endl;

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.data());
    // shaderProgram must be already initialized
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
}

void destroy_texture()
{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &textures[0]);
}

void update_camera()
{
    glm::vec3 right = glm::cross(camera_direction, camera_up);
    glm::vec3 left = glm::cross(right, camera_up);
    if (translate_forward)
    {
        camera_position += camera_direction*dt;
    }
    if (translate_backward)
    {
        camera_position -= camera_direction*dt;
    }
    if (translate_right)
    {
        camera_position += right * dt;
    }
    if (translate_left)
    {
        camera_position -= right * dt;
    }
    if (rotate_up)
    {
        camera_direction = glm::rotate(camera_direction, dt, right);
        camera_up = glm::rotate(camera_up, dt, right);
    }
    if (rotate_down)
    {
        camera_direction = glm::rotate(camera_direction, -dt, right);
        camera_up = glm::rotate(camera_up, -dt, right);
    }
    if (rotate_right)
    {
        camera_direction = glm::rotate(camera_direction, -dt, camera_up);
    }
    if (rotate_left)
    {
        camera_direction = glm::rotate(camera_direction, dt, camera_up);
    }

    if (rotate_z_left)
    {
        camera_direction = glm::rotate(camera_direction, dt, left);
        camera_up = glm::rotate(camera_up, dt, left);
    }
    if (rotate_z_right)
    {
        camera_direction = glm::rotate(camera_direction, -dt, left);
        camera_up = glm::rotate(camera_up, -dt, left);
    }
}

void draw(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    t = (timer::now() - start_time).count() * (float(timer::period::num) / float(timer::period::den));
    dt = (timer::now() - last_time).count() * (float(timer::period::num) / float(timer::period::den));
    update_camera();
    last_time = timer::now();
    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(PI / 4, 1.f / 1.f, 1.0f, 10.0f);
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.3f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    glm::mat4 model = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.f), PI, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "textureSampler"), tex_flag);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, &projection[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, &view[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, &model[0][0]);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6 * 2 * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); // facce * triangoli per faccia * vertici per triangolo
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    GLFWwindow *window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    tex_flag = 0;
    if (!glfwInit())
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

#if defined(__APPLE_CC__)
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
#else
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
#endif
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Project", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    glewExperimental = true;
    if (glewInit() != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
#endif

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    initialize_shader(); check(__LINE__);
    initialize_vao(); check(__LINE__);
    initialize_texture(); check(__LINE__);

    //start = timer::now();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); check(__LINE__);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        draw(window); check(__LINE__);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    destroy_vao(); check(__LINE__);
    destroy_shader(); check(__LINE__);
    destroy_texture(); check(__LINE__);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First order of business when hunting down problems like yours it to minimize the surface area and reduce the program as far as possible yet retaining the problematic behaviour. Your code snippet does not constitute a ***Minimal** Complete Verifyable Example* (MCVE). I stripped it down to a MCVE:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    std::cerr << description << std::endl;
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    std::cout << key << std::endl; 
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    GLFWwindow *window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback( error_callback );
    if (!glfwInit())
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(100, 100, "Project", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Given this minimal example I am *unable* to reproduce your particular problem; i.e. I am getting key events out of this.

That can mean two things: Either the problem resides somewhere else in your code, *or* it is something about your particular system and development environment. This is why MCVEs are so important (especially the *minimal* part); it's the only way to pinpoint the actual culprit.

So here's my suggestion: Try the minimal code I put up and see if it still does not report key events. If so, then it's a problem with your system and not with the code. Otherwise you can re-add layers of functionality piece by piece until it breaks.